# How can I populate a pandas DataFrame with the result of a Snowflake sql query?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using the [Python Connector](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#querying-data) I can query Snowflake:

```
import snowflake.connector

# Gets the version
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=USER,
    password=PASSWORD,
    account=ACCOUNT,
    authenticator='https://XXXX.okta.com',
    )
ctx.cursor().execute('USE warehouse MY_WH')
ctx.cursor().execute('USE MYDB.MYSCHEMA')


query = '''
select * from MYDB.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
LIMIT 10;
'''

cur = ctx.cursor().execute(query)
```

The result is a `snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor`. How can I convert that to a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is now a method `.fetch_pandas.all()` for this, no need for SQL Alchemy anymore.

Note that you need to install snowflake.connector for pandas by doing this

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]
```

Full documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-fetch-pandas-all)

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user="xxx",
            password="xxx",
            account="xxx",
            warehouse="xxx",
            database="MYDB",
            schema="MYSCHEMA"
            )

cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute a statement that will generate a result set.
sql = "select * from MYTABLE limit 10"
cur.execute(sql)
# Fetch the result set from the cursor and deliver it as the Pandas DataFrame.
df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work; something about an error with PyArrow.  Did you ever have this problem?

Comment: According to the [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-pandas#requirements) you need PyArrow 3.0.x. Newer PyArrow versions don't work.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_records()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) or [`pandas.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) with [snowflake-sqlalchemy](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#). The snowflake-alchemy option has a simpler API

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(iter(cur), columns=[x[0] for x in cur.description])
```

will return a DataFrame with proper column names taken from the SQL result. The `iter(cur)` will convert the cursor into an iterator and  `cur.description` gives the names and types of the columns.

So the complete code will be

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

# Gets the version
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=USER,
    password=PASSWORD,
    account=ACCOUNT,
    authenticator='https://XXXX.okta.com',
    )
ctx.cursor().execute('USE warehouse MY_WH')
ctx.cursor().execute('USE MYDB.MYSCHEMA')


query = '''
select * from MYDB.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
LIMIT 10;
'''

cur = ctx.cursor().execute(query)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(iter(cur), columns=[x[0] for x in cur.description])
```

If you prefer using `pandas.read_sql` then you can

```
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL


url = URL(
    account = 'xxxx',
    user = 'xxxx',
    password = 'xxxx',
    database = 'xxx',
    schema = 'xxxx',
    warehouse = 'xxx',
    role='xxxxx',
    authenticator='https://xxxxx.okta.com',
)
engine = create_engine(url)


connection = engine.connect()

query = '''
select * from MYDB.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
LIMIT 10;
'''

df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Comment: @ecerulm i'm using anaconda and cannot install from "snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL"  when i use your first version that doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Maths12 you need to install [snowflake python connector](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-the-python-connector) . I don't use anaconda but I guess either `conda install -c conda-forge snowflake-connector-python` or `pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python`

Comment: @ecerulm  i have installed that , yet i still get the same error

Comment: you need also `snowflake-sqlalchemy` as explained in [Using the Snowflake SQLAlchemy Toolkit with the Python Connector](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html)

Comment: @ecerulm yes i followed that but i get the error: NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake i have tried to resolve this too by looking at other forums but no solution has worked. I will post a question.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to leave here a small change made to the code to ensure that the columns have correct names (in my case the fetch call returned long column names that included information beyond the name itself). I leave it here, in case someone needs it:

```
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

def fetch_pandas(cur, sql):
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = 0
    while True:
        dat = cur.fetchmany(n)
        if not dat:
            break
        a = [cursor.description[i][0] for i in range(len(cursor.description))]
        df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=a)
        rows += df.shape[0]
    return df

n = 100000
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='xxxxx',
    password='yyyyyy',
    account='zzzzz',
    warehouse = 'wwwww',
    database = 'mmmmmm',
    schema = 'nnnnn'
    )

cursor = conn.cursor()

fetch_pandas(cursor, 'select * from "mmmmmm"."wwwww"."table"')
```